# Difference between out.write() and out.print()

Tags: servlets

Why does a **jsp** expression `<%=new Date()%>` will translate to an `out.print(new Date)` in generated Servlet 
and a template text like `<p> example<p>` will translate to an `out.write("<p>example<p>")`